# Checking data type of file read in CLIPS

Tags: clips

As per a homework assignment, I need to read data from a data file.

My data file looks something like this:

```html
Linda A. Martin 43
Phyllis Sebesta 40
Robert Delwood 38
Jack Kennedy 39
Glen Steele 37
```

The issue I'm currently stuck on is how I'm going to parse this appropriately, as I need to sort the list by the two-digit number on the end.

One strategy I thought of is checking the data type as I do a `(read infile)`, but I'm not sure how I'd go about doing that.

My other idea is to read it into an unordered fact and just check the last slot when sorting, but I want to work with the language a little more, so I can utilize some more of the built-in functionality.

Is there any CLIPS functionality that can determine the type of data being read in from an open file?

Comment: oh to be 39 again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some functions you may find useful:

```
CLIPS> (readline)
Glen Steele 37
"Glen Steele 37"
CLIPS> (explode$ (readline))
Glen Steele 37
(Glen Steele 37)
CLIPS> (nth$ 3 (explode$ (readline)))
Glen Steele 37
37
CLIPS> (type (nth$ 3 (explode$ (readline))))
Glen Steele 37
INTEGER
CLIPS> (str-assert (str-cat "(person " (readline) ")"))
Glen Steele 37
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (person Glen Steele 37)
For a total of 2 facts.
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Between the time I posted my question and the time you answered, I actually did something very similar to this. Works very well.